# How to read values with yq when the key has a dot?

Tags: yaml, yq

I am having issues reading values from a YAML file when there's a dot in the key name.

i.e.

```
a:
 b.c: 2
```

Reading the `a` key works fine with `cat mytext.yaml | yq r  - a`. However, when I tried reading `a.b.c` it doesn't give any output.

I tried escaping the dot symbol but that doesn't give any output.

Anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

On v4 onwards, you could simply use the new syntax notation, i.e.

```sh
echo 'a:
 b.c: 2' | yq e '.a."b.c"' -
```

---

In [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you can use the quotes `".."`, to preserve the field containing `.` in your path expression as explained in the documentation [Nested special characters](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/traverse-read#nested-special-characters)

```sh
echo 'a:
 b.c: 2' | yq r - 'a."b.c"'
```

Comment: Hey, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks, for some reason I thought it would be something more similar to jsonpath

Comment: Starting 4.18.1, the `e` is not anymore needed as it is the default and `-` can also be dropped if reading from stdin: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1. We can simplify the command to `yq '.a."b.c"'`

Comment: FYI, in Helm v3.7.2 something like `cat values.yaml | yq '.field."field.with.dots"'` works.